# Can't use @available unavailable with Codable

Tags: swift, codable

I would like to apply the `available` attribute with the `renamed` and `unavailable` arguments to a property of `struct` that conforms to `Codable` , as shown below:

```swift
struct SampleData: Codable {
    @available(*, unavailable, renamed: "newProperty")
    let oldProperty: String
    let newProperty: String
}
```

But when I tried to build this code , I got a compile error like this:

> note: 'oldProperty' has been explicitly marked unavailable here

[image]

If a `struct` does not conform to `Codable`, it works well.

[image]

Does anyone know how to resolve this problem?

And if it is impossible to resolve this, I'd appreciate it if you could tell me why.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post above code as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the synthesised `Codable` conformance is trying to decode/encode `oldProperty` as well. It can't *not* do that, because all stored properties has to be initialised, even if they are unavailable.

It will work if you initialise `oldProperty` to some value, and add a `CodingKey` enum to tell the automatically synthesised conformance to only encode/decode `newProperty`:

```
struct SampleData: Codable {
    @available(*, unavailable, renamed: "newProperty")
    let oldProperty: String = ""
    let newProperty: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case newProperty
    }
}
```

Actually, depending on the situation, you might be able to convert `oldProperty` to a computed property, in which case you don't need the coding keys.

```
struct SampleData: Codable {
    @available(*, unavailable, renamed: "newProperty")
    var oldProperty: String { "" }
    let newProperty: String
}
```